# setting GDB breakpoint for C++ class member function written using template

Tags: python, c++, templates, gdb, breakpoints

I'm trying to set a breakpoint at a C++ class member function which is defined using template. I've looked for the solution in stackoverflow but couldn't find the same problem. Below is a sample code showing the function definition(from py-faster-rcnn caffe code, Dtype is defined as float outside).

```
template <typename Dtype>
void SoftmaxWithLossLayer<Dtype>::Forward_gpu(
    const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& bottom, const vector<Blob<Dtype>*>& top) {
  softmax_layer_->Forward(softmax_bottom_vec_, softmax_top_vec_);
  const Dtype* prob_data = prob_.gpu_data();
  const Dtype* label = bottom[1]->gpu_data();
```

Yesterday, I successfully set the breakpoint using

```
br SoftmaxWithLossLayer<float>::Forward_gpu( const vector<Blob<float>*>& , const vector<Blob<float>*>& )
```

But this morning, it doesn't work! What can be the problem? If I use `br filename:linenuber`, it works.
(BTW, I'm using DDD attached to a process running python including C++ library wrapped by boost but I hope this is irrelevant.)

Comment: Debugging templates has always been a hit-and-miss proposition. In my experience, the most reliable way to set a breakpoint is on the file+line number, rather than a function name.

Comment: I have never tried this but have you considered using nm to determine how it is defined within the shared library?  You might be able to use that information to help ddd/gdb consistently find the template method.

Comment: @ClaudioCorsi, Wow, it looks like that method works. When my `br Solver<float>::Step(int iters)` command didn't work, I searched`Solver.*Step` in the result of `nm _caffe.so` and found only one such function and tried `b _ZN5caffe6SolverIfE4StepEi` and it works! Thanks, next time I'm looking around C++, I'll try using this method! (you can repost it as an answer so that I can choose it as a selected answer).

Comment: @ClaudioCorsi with many C++ class overloaded and inherited functions, it seems hard to find the corresponding function name in `nm` output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never tried this but have you considered using nm to determine how it is defined within the shared library? You might be able to use that information to help ddd/gdb consistently find the template method.